# What do underscores mean in anonymous functions?

Tags: scala, lambda, functional-programming, anonymous-function

I have the method below which I am trying to understand

```
  def method1[A](
    messageCallback: String => A,
    failureCallback: Throwable => Unit = (_: Throwable) => Unit
  ) = {}
```

What does the `(_: Throwable) => Unit)` mean?

I understand that it's the default function literal but I don't understand the underscore.

Comment: `_` means anything. In this case in particular the idea is, given any parameter just ignore it. And the body of the function just returns Unit - in other words the default is an empty callback that does nothing rewarding of the value passed to the callback function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a default implementation of a function. It's so simple that its signature looks almost the same as implementation itself; its signature is `Throwable => Unit`, and it is implemented with the trivial body `(_: Throwable) => Unit`. It means "take some Throwable at input and just don't return anything".

It's the same as implementing it as `(a: Throwable) => Unit`, but then compiler would complain that `a` is unused.

Another alternative for the same thing is `(a: Throwable) => ()`.